# Session Identifier Vulnerability issue in ASP

Tags: security, session, asp-classic

We have a product written in classic ASP. We are going through a security certification for the same. We are not able to pass one of the criteria mentioned as below.

> **Session Token Length and Entropy as follows**
>
> Problem:
>   Length of session ID is 24-characters and session identifiers are not random in nature; they are predictable.
>
> Recommendation: 
>   Session ID should be longer (at least 50 characters) and random in nature.

Does anyone have any suggestion to this?

Comment: 50 chars certainly sounds like overkill to me. 24 random Base64 chars sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Session for anything related to security; implement your own Session-like mechanism using database. For this to work you will have to follow those steps:

1. On every page request, check value of a form variable named "SESSION_TOKEN" (or your own naming of course) and if does not exist, create 50 characters random string then pass it from page to page either on query string or as hidden form value.
2. Use the SESSION_TOKEN as a key to database table called "Session_Data" that will emulate the classic ASP Session collection, holding data for each session based on the above token and having a field storing the last access time so that you can "expire" the data.

This should give you at least a good start. Of course another way will be switching to ASP.NET but guess it already crossed your mind. :)